# Find the number that does not fit into the pattern shown below

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, sequence

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

---

> 12 34 56 78 910 1112 1314 1516 1718 1920 2122 2324 2526 2728 2930 3132 3334 3536

Each row forms a set which implements a pattern. The two patterns are similar but not essentially the same. However, one row contains an element that does not fit into the pattern. Find this element.

Comment: You have posted several intriguing puzzles which do not seem to have any direction given or much commentary on answers. Apparently no-one can solve them correctly. Do they each have a definitive answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think(partial):

> 2122

---

> In the second row,
>  $1920$ can be expressed as $910 *2+100$.
>  $2324$ can be expressed as $1112*2+100$.
>  $2728$ can be expressed as $1314*2+100$... and so on 
> But $2122$ is the only number which cannot be expressed in that form.

Comment: Then how about the first row?

Answer (score 2):

> In the second row you have paired two and two numbers. 910 is the only chunk where the two numbers paired does not have the same number of digits.